# Linker / Compiler / Pre-processing question

Tags: c, compilation, linker, c-preprocessor

in C language:

1.Assume I have the directive #bla. its undefined. is it a compilation error or a preprocessing error?

2.Assume I have 2 .c files: A.c, B.c (and thats it. no .h or anything else.). now, lets say that in A.c I have a function at the global namespace. 
now, I use that function at B.c (which does not know a.c). would it work? will the linker will fill the gaps? do I need to add **at** A.c the func signature in order to use it? or can I juse use it?

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but why dont you just try it out for yourself?

Comment: @Eraklon it is rude.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with invalid directives? Have you tried linking object files the way you're describing?

Comment: Question 1 looks like a type of question asked by programming teachers. It is a poorly written question. As far as the C standard is concerned, preprocessing is a part of language translation. Half a century ago, preprocessing was a separate step. Modern compilers may integrate preprocessing with other compiling steps, and there is not a clear separation between compilation errors and preprocessing errors—preprocessing errors are compilation errors.

Comment: Whether the presence of `#bla` in a source file is an error depends on the C implementation. The C standard does not require that it be diagnosed. All that C 2018 says if it is, in 6.10 9, “The execution of a non-directive preprocessing directive results in undefined behavior.” That means the standard does not impose any requirements, not even a requirement about diagnostic messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You dont need to add function signatures to use it. B.c doesnt need to know anything about function defined in A.c. Linker will fill the gaps. If both B.c and A.c in your project linker will match the function in A.c that you used in B.c

However compiler will warn you about missing function decleration.

# directives are related with preproccessing step. so it is preprocessing error not actual compilation error.

Comment: That can fail badly, though. Compiler assumes `int` return type for non-declared functions, but that might not match the actual return type of the function (could be double, long long or a larger struct). Pretty sure the compiler won't allocate sufficient memory on stack for the return value then, at very least you'll almost certainly get unexpected results. Parameters cannot be checked either and you can end up in quite a mess as well. I'd expect calling functions with such mismatches to be undefined behaviour, but I'm not sure about...

Comment: @Aconcagua You right. But the question is not about what is better or not. question is about,  can it be or not.

Comment: Well, literally asked was *'Would it work?'* – that now depends pretty much on how you define *'to work'*, you seem to be far less strict than me on that question ;)